# User Activity Static/running/Walking/Driving based on CoreMotion data only

Tags: ios, iphone, machine-learning, accelerometer, core-motion

How can we detect user is driving/walking/running/static with CoreMotion data. 
We can get user activity in iPhone 5s using CMMotionActivityManager. But how to get in lower version devices.

With the help of CLLocationManager I can get the device speed and based on speed I can decide the user state, which drain battery life of device.

Is there any possibility to detect Device State based on Core motion only?

Some application like like [Place me](https://www.placemeapp.com/placeme/) app does, It detect user activity based on Coremotion data.

Answer (score 1):

It is nice Machine Learning task. You need to

1. collect lots of data and annotate it (label each sample, whether it is driving/walking/running/static),
2. design a feature vector,
3. then train an appropriate classifier.

The details really wouldn't fit here, I suggest [googleing "accelerometer activity recognition"](https://www.google.com/search?q=accelerometer%20activity%20recognition). In particular, among the first hits I find

- [Human Activity Recognition from Accelerometer Data Using a Wearable Device](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/221258784_Human_Activity_Recognition_from_Accelerometer_Data_Using_a_Wearable_Device/file/5046351407f27390cb.pdf)
- [Activity Recognition from Accelerometer Data](http://joggers-music-app.googlecode.com/svn-history/r79/trunk/acceleromter_related_research_papers/10.1.1.92.1333.pdf)

quite readable, relevant and useful.

The bad news is that it is more work to implement it than you probably think. *Much* more work. :(

In any case, I hope this answer helps a little bit.

Comment: thanks, yes you are right it is time taking process to implement. Currently I am able to make decision whether user is moving or static. But when user is driving, here comes the actual problem. I am not able to differentiate driving and static state. Because while driving also Accelerometer returns same value as while I am static.

Comment: @Bhumeshwerkatre The only thing I can think of: Every now and then the car either accelerates or stops (in a city) or takes turns (highway) or you might even see some specific high frequency but small noise (small vibration). These generate a significantly different pattern in the accelerometer readings than all the others. But you are right, detecting driving seems to be the hardest of those you listed. You might have to sample the accelerometer for 2 minutes to be able to differentiate between static and driving.